# Defining linux command inside vim abbreviations

Tags: linux, vim, abbreviation

I often use abbreviations when using vim editor.
Now I want to use Linux commands when defining vim abbreviations inside /etc/vimrc.

I tried various things but none worked.

My use case:

Inside vim: When I type #! and enter "tab" key, Then the output should be:

```
   #! /usr/bin/env bash
   #Author: Dhimant
   #Date: Realtime date at which command is fired
   #Description:
```

I completed up to first two lines by using "cr" tag

```
ab #!   #!/usr/bin/env bash<cr>#author: Dhimant Thanki
```

But when using "date command", it is not working

```
ab #!   #!/usr/bin/env bash<cr>#author: Dhimant Thanki <cr>#Date: `date` <cr>#Task: (NOT WORKING)
```

So need help in completing this task.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is generally what snippet managers do. I’ve written a template/skeleton program and am working to integrate it to vim which accomplishes slightly different goals. https://github.com/benknoble/tmplr

Comment: You should use snippets to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<C-r>=` to insert a Vim expression:

```
iabbr xxx # Date: <C-r>=strftime('%c')<CR><CR># Second line
```

Note the two `<CR>`s: one to end the expression, and one to insert a newline.

I used `strftime()` here instead of the `date` shell command, as that's easier and will work on all platforms, but you can also use `<C-r>=system('date')[:-2]<CR>` if you prefer (the `[:-2]` is to remove trailing newline).

See: [`:help abbreviations`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#abbreviations), [`:help c_<C-R>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_%3CC-R%3E).

Comment: Thanks, Martin, this was the perfect answer and the thing I wanted.

Comment: Hi Martin, just curious to know if I can use any Linux shell commands inside vim abbreviations?

Comment: Yeah, you can @DhimantThanki, with `<C-r>=system(..)` as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Martin for clearing it out. This helped me very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use snippet engine to achieve what you want. First, you need to install [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511063/why-ultisnips-does-not-recognize-my-own-snippets) on how to set up ultisnips to recognize your own snippets.

Under your custom snippet directory, create a file named `all.snippets` and add the following to this file:

```
snippet #! "bash file header"
#Author: Dhimant
#Date: `!v strftime('%c')`
#Description: just for a test
endsnippet
```

In the above snippet, `!v` is used to execute a Vim command and in this case, [`strftime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604/6064933) to get the current time.

Then open a new file and type `#!` and press Tab. Boom, your custom header is created.
[image]

Comment: Then you should give me a [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)

Comment: No, it is not given. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

The `<cr>` you entered will be interpreted as literally the letters `<cr>`

In order to go down to a new line you can use `<ESC>` to go back to command mode then use `o`.

> O - Begin a new line above the cursor and insert text, repeat [count] times.
>
> o -   Begin a new line below the cursor and insert text, repeat [count] times.

For example:

`ab #!   #!/usr/bin/env bash<ESC>o#author: ErectCrested<ESC>o#Some more text<ESC>o`

Use the last `<ESC>o` if you want to start insert on a new line after the abbreviation, otherwise remove it.

Comment: Hi ErectCrested, Actually I have used <CR> and it is working properly. But my question was to use Linux commands inside vim abbreviations. But no worries, I got the answer. Thank you.