# vimrc command to add uid in insert mode

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I have the following, which in Vim Visual mode inserts an unique alphanumeric string.

```
vnoremap <leader>u :!pwgen -A 8 1<CR>
```

For convenience, I want to do the same thing in Vim Insert mode: something like this (not working: `.vimrc`):

```
iabbrev uuid `pwgen -A 8 1`
```

where the abbreviation `uuid` (or `:uid:` or similar) triggers the BASH `pwgen` command (e.g replacing `uuid` with `moh6sei5`).

---

**Edit**

Per the comment immediately following mentioning [Defining linux command inside vim abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338955/defining-linux-command-inside-vim-abbreviations)

the issue is that `strtime` (there) is a native Vim function (`:h strftime`), whereas `pwgen` is a BASH function. In `.vimrc`:

- works:

  ```
  iabbrev xxx <C-r>=strftime('%c')<CR>
  " Sun 02 Oct 2022 11:03:58 AM PDT
  ```
- does not work:

  ```
  iabbrev uidd <C-r>=pwgen -A 8 1<CR>
  iabbrev uidd <C-r>=!pwgen -A 8 1<CR>
  iabbrev uidd <C-r>=`pwgen -A 8 1`<CR>
  ...
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining linux command inside vim abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338955/defining-linux-command-inside-vim-abbreviations)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; in response please see edit to Question, above. I am also using `SnipMate`, but I find that package to be dated and buggy, so I am trying to move away from it (or alternatives: `UltiSnips`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inoreabbrev <expr> uuid system('pwgen -A 8 1')->trim()
```

Breakdown:

- `<expr>` tells Vim that the right hand side of the abbreviation is to be evaluated as a Vim expression.
- Since `pwgen` is an external command, you need `:help system()` to capture its output.
- External commands often end with a newline character so you need to `:help trim()` it.

Answer (score 1):

This works, `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <F3> <c-r>=trim(system('pwgen -A 8 1'))<cr>
```

Test: Insert mode, typing `apple <F3> banana` gives `apple ipav7lier banana`, where `<F3>` is that key. Each `<F3>` keypress inserts a UID.

---

- `system()`: Vim system() command (`:h system` in Vim)
- `pwgen`: BASH alphanumeric password generator command (`man pwgen` in BASH terminal)
- `pwgen -A 8 1`: lowercase only (-A), 8 characters, 1 password
- `<F3>` : keyboard function 3 key
- See also: https://www.grailbox.com/2021/07/insert-uuids-in-vim-neovim/ ... links to (explanation) https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/bnh7su/inserting_the_output_of_an_external_program_inline/